# Cannot connect to wi-fi network in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, lubuntu

I messed up while trying to uninstall unnecessary packages and ended up breaking my ability to connect to a wi-fi network on my Lubuntu box. What I do see is icons for my network interfaces; clicking on the one for wlan0 lists the ssids and lets me enter the encryption key, but no connection is established after.

What needs to be installed for this to be working once again?

Comment: Check nameserver specified in /etc/resolv.config file

Comment: It is empty. That's for DNS, right? I'm unable to even connect to my router, so I doubt that is related.

Comment: Add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in /etc/resolv.config and restart system once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I fell victim to multiple techniques of network configuration conflicting with one another. In my `/etc/network/interfaces` config file, I had entries for my network interfaces, and the UI in Ubuntu uses the `network-manager` suite of tools. After removing all my devices (except for loopback) from `/etc/network/interfaces`, I was able to use network manager utilities to establish my connection. This also resolved the issue of my boot process taking a long time waiting for network configuration.